# How can I use multiple queryset in a ModelChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I'm just beginning to learn Django and I would like to use different queryset in a ModelChoiceField.

I have 3 models like that :

```
class Politic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Economic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Category(models.Model):
    politic = models.ForeignKey(Politic, blank = True, null = True)
    economic = models.ForeignKey(Economic, blank = True, null = True)
```

And a form like that :

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices = (("0", u"---------"), ("1", u"Politic"), 
                                          ("2",  u"Economic")),
                               required=False)

    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Economic.objects.all(), 
                                      required=False)
```

In my template, I use Ajax to populate my category field with a list of all `Politic` or `Economic` value according to my choice field.
But if I choose `"Politic"`, I have a problem in the validation of my form because the queryset of my category field is `Economic.objects.all()`, not `Politic.objects.all()`.
How can I change my dynamicaly queryset? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can have 2 different selects One for politic and one for economic and show/hide them based on choice field.

Or maybe [Abstract Model Inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id6) would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use a [Generic Relation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) in your `Catagory` model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I try to use your two solutions (Abstract Model and Generic Relation) but it doesn't resolve my problem.
So I create two differents ModelChoiceField (one for Politic and one for Economic) and I use hide/show effects of Jquery in my template (like you say Kugel).
But if you have any others ideas for my problem, I'm interessed.